# Problemas al usar cin.ignore();

Tags: c++

Lo que quiero hacer con `cin.ignore(256,'\n');` es limpiar el buffer de teclado, para que en el 2do bucle `while` pueda ingresar los datos.

Pero al monento de ejecutarlo me doy cuenta de no he logrado mi objetivo, y debido a mi inexperiencia no se que error he estado cometiendo.

Aquí el codigo de lo que he logrado:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
   int a = 0, b = 0, n,i;
   while (cin >> n) {// ingreso " 1 2 3 " y un caracter para cerrar el bucle
      a += n;
   }
   cin.ignore(256,'\n');
   while (cin >> i) {// ingreso " 4 5 6 " y un caracter para cerrar el bucle
      b += n;
   }
   cout << a <<' '<< b << endl;
}
```

Si todo hubiera salido como lo he planeado la salida seria: `6 15`

PERO la salida que obtengo es : `6 0`.

Comment: Creo que si usas el debugger y lees la documentación de std::cin todo te saldrá como lo planeado; y es más, hasta planearás mejor aún. Ánimo!

Comment: @asdasdasd tienes razon, el problema que tenia es que no usaba la instruccion `cin.clear()`. si quieres pones tu comentario como respuesta para darte el ticket

Comment: O mejor, prepara una buena respuesta, mostrando el comportamiento de std::cin y por qué necesitaste invocar  std::cin.clear(); Este ejemplo puede servirte como base: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El programa tiene 2 errores:

#### Primer error

Falta usar `cin.clear()`, que es se encarga de limpiar los flags (**error state flags**), al no hacer esto el segundo `cin` no funcionaba porque los valores de los flags indicaban que se había presentado un `eofbit` (indicando el final del stream).

#### Segundo error

Dentro del segundo while, se tiene `b += n`, pero la variable que se está leyendo es `i`, por lo tanto esto debería ser `b += i`.

Finalmente el programa debería ser:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
   int a = 0, b = 0, n,i;
   while (cin >> n) {// ingreso " 1 2 3 " y un caracter para cerrar el bucle
      a += n;
   }

   cin.clear();  // 1er error, provoca que no entre al siguiente ciclo

   cin.ignore(256,'\n');

   while (cin >> i) {// ingreso " 4 5 6 " y un caracter para cerrar el bucle
      b += i;   // 2do error, suma la variable incorrecta
   }

   cout << a <<' '<< b << endl;
}
```

La salida que se obtiene es:

```
$ ./cin_ignore 
1 2 3 \n
4 5 6 \n
6 15
```